# CPU/Memory utilization via IPMI(OOB) or SNMP

Tags: cpu-usage, snmp, ipmitool, out-of-band

Is it possible to get CPU and Memory utilization via IPMI(Ipmitool) or SNMP out of band.

If yes than how, I am looking to get it for HP Proliant DL360.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible because "out of band" is really out if band. Ipmitool connects to the BMC at the server and BMC is independent on OS running at the main CPUs. BMC is an independent chip that may read various information about HW but memory utilization and CPU utilization is controlled by OS running at main CPUs.

BMC is not aware how the OS organizes memory and there might by a lot of OS versions with specific memory organization schema. Only running OS knows what memory is used and what is free and BMC does not have such information.

Comment: Thanks Zaboj for the explanation, but in Dell they provide iDrac commands to get the out of band utilisation data. So I thought it will be possible in HP too, also when I tried IPMI command to get sensor list I got the CPU usage and Memory usage in Dell server, so do you mean it's not OOB?

Comment: Is it possible to get the same info via SNMP?